# Is it not secure if we use weak passwords to protect exported PKCS #12 files with private keys?

Tags: pki

Consider a practical scenario as described in Microsoft's [Expand Export a Certificate with the Private Key](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754329.aspx). We can see a certificate with private key can be exported as a PKCS #12 file, where the private key can be protected by a password (in Step 7).

Questions:

1. If one day this PKCS #12 file is stolen by a hacker, then, can he perform an offline dictioary attack to this file?
2. Step 5 in that article reads:

   > In the Certificate Export Wizard, click Yes, export the private key. (This option will appear **only if the private key is marked as exportable** and you have access to the private key.)

   How does this mechanism works? Is the (un-)exportability guaranteed by a cryptography algorithm (so that no one can change the property), or only by a software method (so that hackers can change the property)?

Comment: 1. Yes. Decrypting the file with a wrong password would not give a valid key, so the attacker can try again until they find one that works. (I'm not posting this as an answer because I don't know about the second.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If one day this PKCS #12 file is stolen by a hacker, then, can he perform an offline dictioary attack to this file?

Yes, that's possible. The password is simply used to directly derive a symmetric key, which is used in turn to encrypt the private key.

> Is the (un-)exportability guaranteed by a cryptography algorithm (so that no one can change the property), or only by a software method (so that hackers can change the property)?

Generally it is just a bit set to 0 or 1 somewhere. Where and how it is stored depends on the Cryptographic Service Provider (CSP) and the implementation of the key container that contains the private key. If it and the private key are stored in a HSM or Smart Card, it may be tricky to change it.

Comment: P12 is quite old, don't expect too much magic out of it.

Comment: So private certificate files generated by openssh or given by StartSSL also should be stored carefully. If they are stolen, the private keys are in danger, am I right?

Comment: Adding (more) access control is always a good idea. Using long passphrases instead of simple passwords is as well. If possible, store the keys offline but *do* make backups, flash may also loose data in the long run. If you are really serious, use a secure token for the private key so you know that the value itself cannot be copied at least. Instead of backups you may also want to consider a scheme where loss of the private key is not catastrophic (i.e. for signature generation you could use a new key / certificate if the private key is gone / compromised).

Comment: @phan "Marking a key as exportable" is, in general, a Windows-only concept. Most other platforms (smart cards excepted) have no notion of a locally-stored key that can't be exported, because they know they couldn't enforce such a guarantee.

Comment: @MrNerdHair Similar mechanisms (unextractable) are in e.g. the PKCS#11 specification, which covers both hardware and software tokens. Those kind of restrictions may be enforced even if they don't make sense. Besides that there are other mechanisms such as TPM's and other key stores that may have hardware protection or access levels. So I do not fully agree with your comment.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes By "platform" I was thinking of an OS's default system for storing keys. JavaCard provides exportability guarantees, so I mentioned smart cards as an exception, but otherwise Windows's CryptoAPI is the only platform I know of that offers an no-exportability guarantee for key storage. Of course, as you say, throw in hardware tokens (or third party software modules) and all bets are off.

Comment: @MrNerdHair What about the key stores in Android and iOS devices? They can be protected at kernel level, which is different from being in user accessible memory. CPU's themselves sometimes come with secure key stores as well, though that's pretty rare.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Only on mobile would the kernel be considered something that's not under the user's control! Still though, that's a good point. Android not so much, but iOS on devices with an A7 or later chip have a smart-card-like thing called the Secure Enclave that provides hardware protection to keychain elements. Still, on iOS it's not so much that you can mark a key as non-exportable as that there is no API for exporting keys at all. It's more neglect than a security guarantee, and might change in the future.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes In my research on this stimulating subject, I seem to have found that Mac OS 10.6 introduced kSecAttrIsExtractable, even though it's not exposed in the GUI, so I guess my original point about Windows being the only platform dumb enough to offer an unenforceable guarantee of non-exportability wasn't correct. No way it'll happen on Linux though! *crosses fingers*

Comment: @phan OpenSSH normally generates only private keys, not certificates, and does not use PKCS#12 format. 
However, an OpenSSH-format password-encrypted private key and a PKCS#12-format password-encrypted private key 
are both private keys protected by the password, and at risk if the password is weak.